# Assigning a static IP address to DHCP network

Tags: address

I would like to add a static IP address to computer on a DHCP network. If I reserve an IP address for this computer does this result in a static IP address?

Answer (score 9):

Yes and no.

Officially, a static IP address is one that is configured directly on the machine, and as such the device, will not send DHCP discovery packets, but will instead just bring its network interface up with the defined IP

Setting a reservation, will ensure that the device always gets the same IP address, but is not officially a "static" ip, rather it is a reserved DHCP address, also called a "static lease"

For all intents and purposes it will achieve the same result however.

If you decide to set the static directly on the device, make sure you remove the address from the DHCP pool

Comment: ninja'd by @john

Answer (score 0):

It's not a true static if it's a reservation, but for all practical intents and purposes it has the same behavior (assuming your DHCP server is up).